# In pygame, can i use a list to blit an object multiple times with only one line of code?

Tags: python, list, pygame, blit

I am trying to make a platformer in python 2.7 using pygame. I am very inexperienced in using lists in python. i want to make the platforms tileable so that they can be any length. Lets say i wanted it to be 250 pixels long and each individual image was 50 long, could i do something like this:

```
list = [0,1,2,3,4]
screen.blit(platformimg,(list*50+x,y)
```

Also, i figure this part is pretty easy, but how would i make a list that is the length of a certain integer. So if the integer was 3, how could i make the list [0,1,2]?

Comment: First lesson: Don't ever name a `list` "list" because it's a built-in.

Comment: Thanks, i realized that when i actually tried to use the code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're going to need to do something like this:

```
for i in range(6):
    screen.blit(platformimg, (i*50+x, y))
```

See the section titled **Going From The List To The Screen** in this pygame [tutorial](http://www.pygame.org/docs/tut/MoveIt.html).

The reason being because `screen.blit()` does not accept a list argument for the position.

If you have an arbitrary list of x,y positions, then it would be something like:

```
positions = [(100, 30), (250, 90), (42, 623)]
for position in positions:
    screen.blit(platformimg, position)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
valuesList = [x for x in range(listLen)]
```

Where `listLen` is the length you want. Example: `[x for x in range(3)]` produces `[0, 1, 2]`

Comment: same as `list(range(listLen))` and not what he wanted I think